# How to clean the pre-ground coffee funnel of De'Longhi ECAM23.120.B?

Tags: ground-coffee, bean-to-cup

Two weeks ago I tried to make a decaf coffee with pre-ground coffee, but my machine threw a "too much pre-ground coffee" error (used the spoon that came with it BTW).

I tried to clean the pre-ground funnel with a spoon, brush, knife etc. I couldn't see any coffee anymore so I thought it'd be ok.

This morning the bean to cup coffee tastes horrible and the same horrible smell is coming from the pre-ground coffee tunnel.

How do I clean the machine correctly? There's no information about it online. It's a long funnel.

Comment: Would it be feasible to call the manufacturer?  I have a DeLonghi espresso maker but it uses a portafilter (separate grinder).  Instruction manuals [here](https://www.delonghi.com/en-us/manuals/products/coffee-and-espresso/c/coffee).

Comment: Is this [your model's instruction manual](https://www.manua.ls/delonghi/magnifica-s-ecam-23120b/manual)?